# Custom GWT Tree table with TreeItem and FlexTable  

Tags: gwt

GWT does not contain TreeTable but my project requirement with tree table. so I created it by using [Tree](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~Tree) and [FlexTable](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~FlexTable).

Here Bean class: Item

```
class Item
{
ItemType itemType; //Parent,Child Enum type
long parentId;
long amount;
String itemName;
String qty;
String rate;
//Setter / Getter Methods
}
```

This is custom TreeItem class which has relation between parent Item & Child Item. I have Created one row By using TreeItemNode.

```
 public class TreeItemNode extends TreeItem {
        private FlexTable table; //this will use to access child
        private FlexTable parentTable; //This will use to access parent of particular child.
    //This constructor create parent node
       public TreeItemNode(FlexTable parentTable) {
            setWidget(parentTable);
            this.parentTable=parentTable;
            setState(true); 
        }
     //The method used to add Child items in parent
        public TreeItem addItem(Widget widget)  {
            this.table=(FlexTable) widget;
            TreeItem ret = new TreeItem(widget);
            addItem(ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Using Item List, This method is creating the tree which has parent and child node relations.

```
class CustomTreeTable extends Tree
{
    public void createTreeTable() {
            //This map store parent id and tree item object for letter fetch the parent node and add child node in it
              treeItemMap = new HashMap<Long, BOQTreeItem>();
            for (Item item : itemList) {
                if (item.getParentItemId() == 0) {
                //Create new parent node 
                    TreeItemNode itemTreeItem = new TreeItemNode(addChildItem(item,
                            new FlexTable(), true),
                            "gwt-TreeNode");
                    treeItemMap.put(item.getId(), treeItem);
                    addItem(itemTreeItem);
                } else {
                //Add child node
                    if (treeItemMap.containsKey(item.getParentItemId())
                            && treeItemMap.get(item.getParentItemId()) != null) {
                        FlexTable dataFlextable = treeItemMap.get(
                                item.getParentItemId()).getTable();
                        if (dataFlextable == null) {
                            dataFlextable = new FlexTable();
                            treeItemMap.get(item.getParentItemId()).setTable(
                                    dataFlextable);
                        }
                        FlexTable treeTable = addChildItem(item, dataFlextable,
                                false);
                        treeItemMap.get(item.getParentItemId()).addItem(treeTable);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Using this my table is as below. + is my tree node open/ close like:

```
ItemName qty rate amount
+ item1   11   1   11   //parent item
---------------------------
- item2   11   2   22
--------------------------------
    SubItemName qty rate amount //child item
     subItem1    5   2    10
     subItem2    8   5    40
------------------------------------
```

The problem is when I want calculate qty* rate in one raw (child item) than I can do using row index but  if I want to do calculate all the child item & show in parent row. then logic become so complex. so I just want to know the logic which I implemented like store the instance in map and managed. is it proper? I am going in right direction or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a DataGrid Widget will be simpler for what you are trying to achieve.

Look at the GWT ShowCase : [here](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid)

On the DataGrid, you have childs under parent row displaying when you click on ShowFriends link.

Hope it helps. :)